# How to send image as part of email body in django

Tags: python, django, email, html-email, django-email

I am building a portal for sending dynamic emails. Part of the form is an image field which the user can upload an image which I would like to be rendered in the image body, not as an attachment after the form is filled out. This is my code:

views.py

```
def emailView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            recipient = form.cleaned_data['recipient']

            image_url = Email.objects.all().last()
            domain = request.get_host()

            final_image = str(domain) + str(image_url.image.url)

            msg = loader.render_to_string(
                'email_portal/email.html',
                {
                    'name': name,
                    'subject': subject,
                    'domain' : domain,
                    'final_image' : final_image,
                    'image_url': image_url,
                    'message': message,
                }
            )

            try:
                 send_mail(subject, name, message, [recipient]
            , fail_silently=True, html_message=msg,)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('/')
    else:

        form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    return render(request, "email_portal/index.html", {'form': form})
```

email.html

```
<h5>{{ final_image }}</h5> #missing forward slash
<a href="{{ domain }}/{{ image_url.image.url }}">My link</a> #missing forward slash
<tr>
<td background="{{ final_image }}</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried concatenating the host and the file path but for some reason, in the email body it's structured correctly but I can't render it as a background image and when I try to click it a forward slash is missing between the host and file path.

Comment: Which reference is having the problem? Is it the one inside the `h5`, `a href` of `td background`?

Comment: All tags have the same issue. The URL is well constructed in the email but when I click it a forward slash is missing between the host and the file path and in`td` the image is not rendered

Comment: Can you share the final value of `final_image`?

Comment: http://mzawadiemail.mzawadi.com/media/images/bentleymotors-20200126-0001.jpg

Comment: Does the `a href` doesn't work? You've explicitly added a forward slash...

Comment: It doesn't it redirects me to the same invalid link

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `{{ final_image }}` is the same as `{{ domain }}/{{ image_url.image.url }}` and doesn't add anything else other than the url, I would try this:

```
<td style="background-image: url('{{ final_image }}');">
```

It's a minor tweak to what you were doing, but it works. However, this will not work in Outlook 2007-2019.

For a solution to work in most email clients including Outlook, I would try this instead:

```
<td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-image: url('{{ final_image }}'); 
background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
  style="width:600px;height:400px; background-position: center center !important;">
  <v:fill type="tile" src="{{ final_image }}" />
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

One issue with Outlook is that if you do not put up a width and a height and the image is larger than the width of the email, Outlook will display the full width of the image. CSS styles like `max-width` or `width` are ignored. So unless you have some code to process the image size to a max width, it is a consideration.

`background-size: cover !important;` will ensure modern email clients fill the gap to the size you specify as the maximum width.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue, the link is redirecting me to a malformed URL which doesn't have a forward slash between the host and image path